# Arrays of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python and I am stuck with probably a very stupid thing. So, I need to create an array of tuples (I know lists would be better, but its just my task... maybe a cast at the end?) with evenly spaced numbers. The touples should be of lenght 1 to 3.
I came up with this very trivial solution:

```
array = [(int(x),int(y),int(z)) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6) for y in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6) for z in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6)]
array.append((int(x),int(y)) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 11) for y in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 11))
array.append((int(x),) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 18))
```

But when I then print the array it contains only the touples with 3 elements, as the append functions didn't work (though no error is given).

I couldn't find anything that could help me on the internet and thus I am here to ask two questions:

- Is there a smarter way to accomplish the result I want? (Just to know current Python "state of the art", possibly in a single line)
- Why this code does not do what I think it should do? (So I can get a better understanding of the things I am using).

Thank you a lot yout help is appreciated.

Comment: please tag numpy questions correctly, so we can avoid them if we don't know numpy. you had me scratching my had, how this could even _be_ an "array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things here. First, you are actually working with `list` and not numpy arrays.
Second, the numpy arrays are not efficient if you do not fix their size.. It is best to avoid expending or appending to a numpy array. Now about your code:

The first line is creating a list of tuples of size 3 with the desired values.

```
array = [(int(x),int(y),int(z)) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6) for y in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6) for z in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6)]
# len() = 216
```

Then what you pass to the `append()` method is actually a generator

```
((int(x),int(y)) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 11) for y in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 11))
# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000184FE7DB360>
```

So it does nothing... Same for the third line. I'm quite surprised this syntax doesn't through an error.

Now the solution, it's to use `extend()`. This method will take a list as an argument, and will extend the first list.

```
array = [(int(x),int(y),int(z)) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6) for y in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6) for z in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 6)]
array.extend([(int(x),int(y)) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 11) for y in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 11)])
array.extend([(int(x),) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 18)])

# len() = 355 you got all the items.
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to get the same result just in the declaration, without other functions being called?

Comment: @Thanatopseustes I assume that what you mean by your question is to do the same in one line. Since the number of points changes depending on the size of the tuple, I don't see a way to do it all at once.

Comment: @Thanatopseustes However, extending or appending to list is quite efficient... If you don't try to extend with a million elements it should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use extend instead of append:

```
array.extend((int(x),int(y)) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 11) for y in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 11))
array.extend((int(x),) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 61, num = 18))
```

Currently, you are appending generator objects instead of tuples.